# Bad request - parameter error : 2Checkout API

Tags: api, 2checkout

im just new in using 2checkout API

i've declared the `sellerId`,`publishableKey`,`privateKey` correctly, but it gives me and error of "Bad request - parameter error"

can anyone help me about this?

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you forgot the token or did you switch between private and publishable keys

Comment: hi @Luis i think i fixed the parameter error, but now ..
i have another error, it gives me an error of

`Unauthorized`

i've search about it, they say that i happens when `billingAdr` is empty or hidden, but i did not hide it and its not empty at all

what do you think about this?